# Take an object from an array of objects based on the max value on one of its properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, filter

Let's say I got an array of object like this

```
const arr = [
  {name: 'John', age: 15},
  {name: 'Max', age: 17},
  {name: 'Tom', age: 11},
]
```

How can I take just the object containing Max, 17?
This would be the result

```
b = [{ name: Max, age: 17 }]
```

or better

```
c = { name: Max, age: 17 }
```

Comment: Did you try anything? You could sort by age and take the first. You could loop and track the highest value and return the index. Look up the sort function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reduce the array to the object with highest `age`:

```js
const arr = [{"name":"John","age":15},{"name":"Max","age":17},{"name":"Tom","age":11}]

const result = arr.reduce((acc, o) => !acc || o.age > acc.age ? o : acc, null)

console.log(result)
```

I'm using `null` as the default value for the `Array.reduce()` to prevent an error if the array is empty. However, you can check for an empty array beforehand as well:

```js
const findMaxAge = arr => arr.length 
  ? arr.reduce((acc, o) => o.age > acc.age ? o : acc)
  : null

const arr = [{"name":"John","age":15},{"name":"Max","age":17},{"name":"Tom","age":11}]

console.log(findMaxAge(arr))

console.log(findMaxAge([]))
```

Comment: Nice one liner!

Comment: Very elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort by age first, then the object with the highest age value will be at the start of the list:

```
const a = [
  {name: "John", age: 15},
  {name: "Max", age: 17},
  {name: "Tom", age: 11},
]

const sortedByAge = a.sort((a,b) => b.age - a.age);

const highestAge = sortedByAge[0];

console.log(highestAge);
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this code helping you

```
const a = [{name: 'John', age: 15},
       {name: 'Max', age: 17},
       {name: 'Tom', age: 11},];
const result = a.reduce((p, c) => p.age > c.age ? p : c);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `Array.prototype.reduce()` is a clean way.
this function iterates through the array one by one, at each step adding the current array value to the result from the previous step. in our case will compare the previous largest element to the current. the return value will be the object containing the largest value for the age key.

```js
const arr = [
       {name: 'John', age: 15},
       {name: 'Max', age: 17},
       {name: 'Tom', age: 11},
    ]
    
const largest = arr.reduce((prev, current) => (prev.age > current.age) ? prev : current)

console.log(largest);
```